# Docker driver_opts.type=none?

Tags: docker, sockets, docker-compose

What does type=none do? e.g.

```
volumes:
  transmission_config:
    driver: "local"
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
```

[Lots of people](https://github.com/search?l=yaml&p=6&q=%22driver_opts%22&type=Code) are using it but I can't find where any of this is documented.

Where are all the driver options documented?

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59837131/1988326) from LinPy, the options specified under `driver_opts` are similar to the options that are used for the `mount` command.

Looking into what `type="none"` does in the `mount` command, I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136689/375694) that says:

> The `none` just means that there is no physical disk partition linked to the mount point you see when issuing the mount command. It is used for virtual filesystems like `shm`, `ramfs`, `proc` and `tmpfs`.

Which makes sense to use for local Docker volumes as well that are not associated with a specific partition.